# Using a .ppk key with `ssh`

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have a PuTTY `.ppk` key. How do I use it with `ssh`/OpenSSH on Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use PuTTYgen to convert it to the apropriate format.

- If you need the private key, use PuTTYgen's *Conversions → Export OpenSSH key* menu item on Windows, or run the following command on Linux:

  ```
  puttygen MyKey.ppk -O private-openssh -o MyKey.key
  ```
- If you only need the public half, copy&paste it from PuTTYgen's "Public key for pasting" box. On Linux, use a similar command as above, only replacing `private-openssh` with `public-openssh`.

  [image: Screenshot]

(On Linux, PuTTYgen is usually available in the package `putty` or `putty-tools`.)